# How to add image to react-native-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using **react-native-maps** to deal with maps. Now I want to add bunch of images like a polygon to map. For existing polygon, it has something like:

[image]

I want to replace that with the polygon below.

[image]

**Can we add image with defined coordinates, like polygon?** (I know we can define polygon position by adding array of coordinates for *react native*, but for images I don't know)

Answer (score 1):

is the image a .tif? is it georeferenced? You could use something like [MapTiler to georeference the image](https://youtu.be/bTlv6u5i2Rc), then publish to the map using [UrlTiles](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/tiles.md)

Comment: This is excellient answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).